# Annotation processing exception: failed to analyze: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

Tags: kotlin, annotation-processing, annotation-processor

I'm writing my own annotation processor and I want to be able to annotate the return type of a function.

Here's the code for the annotation:

```
@Retention(AnnotationRetention.SOURCE)
@Target(AnnotationTarget.FUNCTION)
annotation class ReturnType(val type: KClass<*>)
```

And part of the code from the annotation processor:

```
annotatedElement.enclosedElements
    .filter { it.kind == ElementKind.METHOD }
    .forEach { method ->
        val returnType = method.getAnnotation(ReturnType::class.java).type
    }
```

When I try to compile the code I get the following exception:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: failed to analyze:
>   java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException   at
>   org.jetbrains.kotlin.analyzer.AnalysisResult.throwIfError(AnalysisResult.kt:56)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.compileModules$cli(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:182)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:165)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:55)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.kt:84)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.kt:42)
>     at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLITool.exec(CLITool.kt:104)     at
>   org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.compile(CompileServiceImpl.kt:1558)
>     at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor104.invoke(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)   at
>   java.rmi/sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:359)
>     at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)   at
>   java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)    at
>   java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>     at
>   java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
>     at
>   java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:562)
>     at
>   java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:796)
>     at
>   java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:677)
>     at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native
>   Method)   at
>   java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:676)
>     at
>   java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
>     at
>   java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
>     at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) Caused by:
>   java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException   at
>   jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor122.invoke(Unknown Source)
>     at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)   at
>   org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.base.AnnotationProcessingKt.doAnnotationProcessing(annotationProcessing.kt:76)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.base.AnnotationProcessingKt.doAnnotationProcessing$default(annotationProcessing.kt:35)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.AbstractKapt3Extension.runAnnotationProcessing(Kapt3Extension.kt:224)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.AbstractKapt3Extension.analysisCompleted(Kapt3Extension.kt:187)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.ClasspathBasedKapt3Extension.analysisCompleted(Kapt3Extension.kt:98)   at
>   org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM$analyzeFilesWithJavaIntegration$2.invoke(TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.kt:97)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.analyzeFilesWithJavaIntegration(TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.kt:107)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.analyzeFilesWithJavaIntegration$default(TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.kt:82)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler$analyze$1.invoke(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:557)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler$analyze$1.invoke(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:82)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.messages.AnalyzerWithCompilerReport.analyzeAndReport(AnalyzerWithCompilerReport.kt:107)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.analyze(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:548)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.compileModules$cli(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:177)
>     ... 22 more Caused by:
>   com.sun.tools.javac.processing.AnnotationProcessingError:
>   javax.lang.model.type.MirroredTypeException: Attempt to access Class
>   object for TypeMirror int     at
>   jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.callProcessor(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:992)
>     at
>   jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.discoverAndRunProcs(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:896)
>     at
>   jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment$Round.run(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:1222)
>     at
>   jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.doProcessing(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:1334)
>     at
>   jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.processAnnotations(JavaCompiler.java:1258)
>     at
>   jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.processAnnotations(JavaCompiler.java:1157)
>     ... 38 more Caused by: javax.lang.model.type.MirroredTypeException:
>   Attempt to access Class object for TypeMirror int     at
>   jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.model.AnnotationProxyMaker$MirroredTypeExceptionProxy.generateException(AnnotationProxyMaker.java:309)
>     at
>   java.base/sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationInvocationHandler.invoke(AnnotationInvocationHandler.java:86)
>     at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy48.type(Unknown Source)  at
>   annotation.CreateNoOpProcessor.generateClass(CreateNoOpProcessor.kt:64)
>     at annotation.CreateNoOpProcessor.process(CreateNoOpProcessor.kt:43)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.base.incremental.IncrementalProcessor.process(incrementalProcessors.kt)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.base.ProcessorWrapper.process(annotationProcessing.kt:147)
>     at
>   jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.callProcessor(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:980)
>     ... 43 more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution can be found at the following link:
https://area-51.blog/2009/02/13/getting-class-values-from-annotations-in-an-annotationprocessor/

The trick is to catch the MirroredTypeException and extract the typeMirror from it.

```
val returnType: TypeMirror? = try {
    method.getAnnotation(ReturnType::class.java)?.type
    null
} catch (e: MirroredTypeException) {
    e.typeMirror
}
```